# Windows 2000 will be end of life on the next patch day, but will it still receive patches on that day?

Tags: windows-update, windows-2000, patch

I still have a few old Win9x VMs I can no longer reinstall because their update services do not longer work. So, I'd like to use [WSUS Offline Update](http://www.wsusoffline.net/) to burn a CD with all Windows 2000 updates after the last updates arrive, but before they are no longer available...

I know that Windows 2000 support ends next patch day. My question:

- Will updates still be available after that day or will I have to create that CD before that date?
- Will the next patch day still include patches for Windows 2000 (if there are holes) or are the current patches all that will ever be available (assuming there is no out-of-band patching this month)?

Comment: does really nobody know this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, as it is in the past now: Microsoft still provides all old updates, and it did patch Windows 2000 on the last patch day.